# How can we read list of dictionaries in apache beam in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a text file which contains list of dictionaries.
Now , I want to read it using apache beam,and return individual dictionaries from list.
How can I do it.
My text file like this.
[{"id":1,"name":"A"},{"id":2,"name":"B"}]

Comment: I proposed you an answer, please let me know if it help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To read `Json` file with `Beam`, the format should be [Newline Delimited JSON](http://ndjson.org/) instead of standard `Json` as you proposed in your question, example :

```json
{"id":1,"name":"A"}
{"id":2,"name":"B"}
```

You can then use `ReadFromText` input connector :

```py
def run():
    custom_pipeline_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(CustomPipelineOptions)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        inputs:PCollection[str] = p | "Read Json" >> ReadFromText("gs://bucket/input.json")
       
        ....
```

- The result is a `PCollection` of `str`
- You can apply a transformation a the current `Json` String if needed (for example deserialize the `String` to a `Dict`)